# How can I optimally modify this BiqQuery query to retrieve the latest available data

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have the following query. It initially performs a sub-select by querying on a table that is partitioned (sharded) by `sample_date_time`. It does this by filtering using a date range in the `WHERE` that is passed via parameters. Then the final `SELECT` selects the data to be returned.

The query currently returns data for the *latest* complete hour (from the beginning of the previous hours hourly boundary, to the end of it). I want to adapt it to instead to get the latest hour of data that contains *any* data sample, up to a maximum of *approximately* 5hrs ago. The query can't use anything that invalidates the BigQuery cache within any given hour (e.g. I can't use a  date function that gets the current date). The table data only updates every hour.

I'm thinking maybe I need to select the max `sample_date_time` in the initial sub-select, over a range of the last 5 hours. I could pass the hourly end boundary of the current time as a parameter, but I'm not seeing how I can limit the date range for which to retrieve the `MAX`, then use that max to get the start and end dates of the most recent hour that has any data.

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
  created_date_time,
  sample_date_time,
  station,
  channel,
  value
  FROM my.mart
  WHERE sample_date_time BETWEEN '2019-07-23 04:00:00.000000+00:00' AND '2019-07-23 04:59:59.999000+00:00'
  AND station = '[my_guid]'
)
SELECT sample_date_time, station, channel, value
FROM data
ORDER BY value desc, channel asc, sample_date_time desc
```

Comment: i didn't get it  - you just explained what to do in section above the presented code - so have you tried to follow this idea? should be straightforward I think

Comment: if you could simplify your example and remove not relevant/significant to your case - this would make it easier for us to help you. I feel like this should be relatively simple - but your example is too bushy to jump in - might be just for me though